# Shortest list in list of list (Haskell)

Tags: list, haskell, short

How do I get the shortest list given a list of lists?

I have

```
 shortest :: [[a]] -> [a]
 shortest [] = []
```

And I really don't know where to go from there to be honest
Appreciate any help

Comment: A funny way is the function `snd.head.sort.map((,)=<<length)` ;)

Answer (score 6):

First what you have already:

```
 shortest [] = []
```

I actually don't like this very much because this means there is no difference between

```
shortest []
```

and

```
 shortest [[]]
```

But, if you like this behavior then Data.List has `minimumBy` which has the type

```
(a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> a
```

So we first need that `(a -> a -> Ordering)` which we can get with `compare` and a useful little function called `on` from Data.Function. `on` acts like a "nozzle" of sorts and applies a function to 2 arguments before feeding them into another function.

```
 cmp = compare `on` length
```

Which just gives us

```
 shortest = minimumBy cmp
```

But this breaks when given an empty list so

```
  shortest [] = []
  shortest ls = minimumBy cmp ls

  shortest [] = Nothing
  shortest ls = Just $ minimumBy cmp ls
```

Comment: And if you don't like that, make it `shortest :: [[a]] -> Maybe [a] ; shortest [] = Nothing ; shortest ls = Just $ minimumBy cmp ls`

Comment: @SebastianRedl Yep, the joy of maybe, and that `Ord` constraint isn't necessary

Comment: D'oh! Edited my comment.

Comment: `compare \`on\` f` is the same as `comparing f`

Comment: @jozefg I'm still not sure on how I would write it, seems a bit complex from my little experience with Haskell :S

Comment: @AndyOHart What do you find confusing? I'm happy to explain

Comment: `minimumBy (comparing length)` looks so nice. It’s such a shame how it breaks on an empty list or infinite-list elements. :(

Answer (score 2):

Here is a version that can handle infinite lists and should take the least time on average (regardless of the position of the shortest list)

This solution walks down the lists in parallel which avoids reading a very long (or infinite) list first. If all the lists are infinite then this solution could crash. However, since it is tail recursive you shouldn't run out of stack space and this solution should work on very long, but finite, lists.

```
shortest :: [[a]] -> [a]
shortest [] = []
shortest [soleList] = soleList
shortest lists = lists !! ((fst $ head $ winner) - 1)
   where
     winner = shortest' $ zipWith (,) [1..] lists


shortest' :: [(Int, [a])] -> [(Int, [a])]
shortest' plist = if (not $ null nullList)
                    then nullList
                    else shortest' $ map (\(index, list) -> (index, tail list)) 
                                   $ filter (not . null . snd) plist
   where
      nullList = filter (null . snd) plist
```

Please note what happens when multiple shortest lists occur: it returns the first one it encounters. It is possible this is fine, but you might actually want to return more than one list. However, that is outside the scope of the question as currently defined since you are only returning a single list.

EDIT ------------
on further reflection, once we've concluded we don't have the shortest list then we know none of the lists are empty. Thus, shortest' can be simplied to:

```
shortest' :: [(Int, [a])] -> [(Int, [a])]
shortest' plist = if (not $ null nullList)
                    then nullList
                    else shortest' $ map (\(index, list) -> (index, tail list)) plist
   where
      nullList = filter (null . snd) plist
```

Comment: I fear this will keep all of the lists alive during the search for the shortest list, but it would be sufficient to keep the remaining candidates alive. To avoid this, maybe pair the lists with themselves instead of with their index?

Comment: The implementation of `shortest'` looks like it could benefit from list comprehensions. For example, the recursive call would become something like `shortest' [(index, tail list) | (index, list) <- plist, not (null list)]`.

Comment: Toxaris, you can't discard any lists until you reach the end of the shortest one so I don't know how you could know which one NOT to keep alive.

Comment: Ok I see. Before we find the first empty list, we know nothing. After we find it, we know the full answer.

Answer (score 1):

I try to explain how to implement this function "by hand", step by step.

#### The shortest list of zero lists.

The question already contains a case for the empty list of lists.

```
shortest :: [[a]] -> [a]
shortest [] = []
```

Not sure that's perfect, but let's leave it as-is.

#### The shortest list of one list.

We have to add a case for the list that contains exactly one list.

```
shortest [soleList] = ...
```

Clearly, if there is only one list, that one list is also the shortest list.

```
shortest :: [[a]] -> [a]
shortest [] = []
shortest [soleList] = soleList
```

#### The shortest list of many lists

We also need to add a case for bigger lists of lists.

```
shortest (firstList : remainingLists) = ...
```

There are two alternatives for where the shortest list is: Either the shortest list is `firstList`, or the shortest list is one of the lists in `remainingLists`. If the latter, than it has to be not just any list in `remainingLists`, but the shortest list in there. So we need a recursive call on `remainingLists`.

```
shortest (firstList : remainingLists) =
    ... firstList ... shortest remainingLists ...
```

How should we fill the ...? We just select the shorter of the two lists.

```
shortest :: [[a]] -> [a]
shortest [] = []
shortest [soleList] = soleList
shortest (firstList : remainingLists) =
    shortestOfTwo firstList (shortest remainingLists)
```

#### The shortest list of two lists

How do we select the shorter of the two lists?

```
shortestOfTwo :: [[a]] -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
shortestOfTwo firstList secondList = ...
```

We just compare their length!

```
shortestOfTwo firstList secondList =
    if length firstList < length secondList
      then firstList
      else secondList
```

### What's next?

This should work, but here are some ideas for how to improve it:

- How often is `length` called on each list?
- What happens for a list that contains infinite lists, such as `shortest [[1, 2, 3], [1..]]`?
- Can you generalize from "shortest list in a list of lists" to "smallest element in a list"?

Answer (score 0):

This solution is heavily based on Tim's answer.

```
import Data.List (find)

shortest :: [[a]] -> Maybe [a]
shortest lists
  = fmap fst . find (null . snd) . zip lists
  . head . filter (any null)
  . iterate (map (drop 1)) $ lists
```

You have to read body of `shortest` backwards. The last line keeps removing one element from each of the lists. The but-last line stops that process when the first empty list is seen. And the first line selects the original list that became empty first.

Differences from Tim's solution:

- point-free style with only standard functions instead of explicit recursion
- return Nothing in the base case
- no tuples during the "search for smallest list" phase
- nontermination for `shortest [[1..]]`

Comment: Well at that point you might as well add a fromJust up at the front to keep the original questions type signature the same and handle the empty list case with pattern matching